# Looping ADF Cointegration PValue on multiple Time Series

Tags: r, loops, oracle-adf

I have stock price data in the following format and I am trying to test all possible permutations for cointegrated spreads.

My current data format:

AAPL     GOOG     IBM     …
415.89   898.39   191.76  …
414.15   899.45   187.55  …
417.27   895.62   190.99  …

I would like to use R to calculate the cointegration P-value (using ADF/Johansen or anything else) for all permutations of ticker time series' and display an output with pairs ranked by P-Value.

For example:

Pair:                P-Value:
AAPL - GOOG          .0196   - Cointegrated
IBM  - GOOG          .0477   - Cointegrated
AAPL - IBM           .0679   - Not Cointegrated

I think this is a fairly straightforward loop but I am not 100% sure how to do this.

Here is a snippet of code that might help:

```
library(tseries)
cointegration<-function(x,y)
{
   vals<-data.frame(x,y)
   beta<-coef(lm(vals[,2]~vals[,1]+0,data=vals))[1]
   (adf.test(vals[,2]-beta*vals[,1], alternative="stationary", k=0))$p.value
}
```

Comment: there's already a function to get residuals : `?residuals` (so no need for `val[,2] - beta * vals[,1]`)

Comment: there is already a function in `urca` package to compute the cointegration.

Comment: @Metrics I found `urca` for more complete than `tseries::adf.test` but it looks like a lot people sadly prefer the latter for cointegration analysis

Comment: exactly; may be they are unaware of that package

Comment: Ok so I think I'm getting closer to the answer. Here is some code that loops through all possible time series combinations for correlation. All I think I need to do is add the cointegration Pvalue inside the loop. Any help on how to implement this in the cleanest and most robust way? (ca.jo or URCA??)

Comment: library(plyr)

XLFvols <- read.csv(file = "data.csv",header=TRUE,sep =",")

combos <- combn(ncol(XLFvols),2)

adply(combos, 2, function(x) {
  test <- cor.test(XLFvols[, x[1]], XLFvols[, x[2]])

  out <- data.frame("Row" = colnames(XLFvols)[x[1]]
                , "Column" = colnames(XLFvols[x[2]])
                , "cor" = round(test$statistic,3)
                ,  "df"= test$parameter
                ,  "p.value" = round(test$p.value, 30)
                )
 return(out)

})